# Control Shell.Explorer.2 with google maps issue in VFP

Tags: visual-foxpro

I have a form in VFP9 that shows a map in a control Shell.Explorer.2. In previous Google API the form works fine, but now the control doesn't show the page, and an Script Error appears:

The page is a simple marker from

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es

Inside of the VFP form I have a TEXT ENDTEXT block, in order to create a temporal webpage(MyHtml.htm) that is shown in the control.
The error indicate the follows lines as error:

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY-GOOGLE-API-KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

If I display the page in IExplorer 11, Firefox, Chrome, Edge, works fine, but with the control Shell.Explorer.2 I get an error and the control doesn't show the map. If I remove the Script, the control doesn't show the map.
Is this type of script no longer supported in shell.explorer.2?
Any documentation or help?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have provided only partial code to talk upon. This sample code, which was written as an answer to a question on Foxite works well and use Shell.Explorer:

```
Local lcCoordinates, lat, lon, lcUrl
lcCoordinates = [14 ° 53'38.5 "N, 24 ° 30'31.0" W]
Alines(laParts, m.lcCoordinates, 1+4, '°',"'",'"' ,' ')
lat = Str((Val(laParts[1]) + Val(laParts[2])/60 + Val(laParts[3])/3600) * Iif(laParts[4] = 'N',1,-1),9,6)
lon = Str((Val(laParts[5]) + Val(laParts[6])/60 + Val(laParts[7])/3600) * Iif(laParts[8] = 'E',1,-1),9,6)

lcUrl = Textmerge("https://www.google.com/maps/@<< m.lat >>,<< m.lon >>,11z")

ShowMap(m.lcUrl)

Procedure ShowMap(tcUrl)
    Public oForm
    oForm = Createobject('form1')
    oForm.Show()
    oForm.HTMLViewer.Navigate2(m.tcUrl)
Endproc

Function GetHTML
    Local myVar
    TEXT to myVar noshow
    ENDTEXT
    Return myVar
Endfunc

Define Class HTMLViewer As OleControl
    OleClass = 'Shell.Explorer'

    Procedure Refresh
        Nodefault
    Endproc

    Procedure LoadHTML(tcHTML)
        With This
            .Navigate2("about:blank")
            .Document.Write(m.tcHTML)
        Endwith
Enddefine

Define Class form1 As Form
    Height = 600
    Width = 800
    Caption = "HTML sample"

    Add Object HTMLViewer As HTMLViewer With ;
        Top = 10, ;
        Left = 10, ;
        Height = 580, ;
        Width = 780, ;
        Anchor = 15,;
        Visible = .T., ;
        Name = "HTMLViewer"

    Procedure Init
        Lparameters tcHTML
        If !Empty(m.tcHTML)
            With Thisform.HTMLViewer
                .LoadHTML(m.tcHTML)
            Endwith
        Endif
    Endproc

    Procedure HTMLViewer.NavigateError
        Lparameters pdisp, url, frame, statuscode, Cancel
        Set Step On
        Cancel = .T.
    Endproc

    Procedure HTMLViewer.BeforeNavigate2
        Lparameters pdisp, url, Flags, targetframename, postdata, headers, Cancel
        Cancel = .T.  && prevents actual navigation
    Endproc

    Procedure HTMLViewer.Refresh
        Nodefault
    Endproc
Enddefine
```